# Editor Log-In Through WordPress

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

Rookie here. Installed CiviCRM WordPress plug-in, and it works great. We've given permissions to several people for entering contact data, events, etc., however, I would prefer they not go in through the WP dashboard, to keep them from accidentally messing up the website from poking around.
Is there a way to create a WP log-in page for them so they can get into CiviCRM without going through the WP dashboard? If it's in the setup, I'm afraid I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress allows you to specify a redirect in the URL.  So if you make this their "Log In" link:

https://example.org/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.9to5.org%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3DCiviCRM&reauth=1

They'll drop into the CiviCRM dashboard upon successful login.  Replace `example.org` with your own URL, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to Peter's login redirect plugin. Very simple and you can setup redirects by WordPress roles. https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/